# TextField text to float (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, iphone

How do I convert the text inside of a TextField to a float in Objective-C?

Answer (score 9):

`float myFloat = [[myTextField text] floatValue];`

Edit: technically the most proper way to do this would be to use an `NSNumberFormatter`, since that will return a `nil` `NSNumber` if it can't parse the string properly, whereas `floatValue` will just return 0.0 for a malformed string.  But `floatValue` is usually adequate for most purposes.

Answer (score 4):

If it's an `NSTextField` you call `floatValue` on the actual object, not on what's returned from `text`.  `NSTextField` does not have a `text` method.

`float myFloat = [myTextField floatValue];`

Comment: +1 good point.  You can also do: `float myFloat = [[myNSTextField stringValue] floatValue];`.  I think (semantically) it makes more sense to get the floatValue from the string, because I don't think it makes sense to call `floatValue` on a textField.  Do you convert a textfield to a float, or do you convert the contents of a textfield to a float?  This is just my pedantic opinion, but I think it makes more sense. :)

Comment: My point is `NSTextField` does not respond to the method `text`.  `stringValue` yes, `text` no ;)

Comment: Apparently this is an iPhone SDK question and UITextField does in fact have a 'text' method. My mistake